# How to install tkgate1.8

Tags: software-installation

The updated version of tkgate is bit laggy. It hangs frequenty. So, I just want to install **tkgate** of version **1.8**. I tried but I couldn't make it.

Comment: What did you try that didnt work out?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkgate/files/tkgate/1.8/tkgate-1.8.tgz/download) is the download link for **tkgate 1.8.0**.
Extract and follow the *README* file for installation.

> **INSTALLATION**
>
> To install tkgate follow the steps below:
>
> 0. Obtain and install tcl/tk 8.0 or later.
>
> 1. cd to the directory in which you unpacked this distribution.
>
> 2. Run the configuration script:
>
> `./configure`
>
> The script will run a series of tests to discover properties of your environment and edit the config.h file. The specific properties that
>   are tested are:
>
> - O/S:             (FreeBSD, SunOS, Linux, other)
> - Compiler:             (gcc or cc)
> - Tcl/Tk Version:           (8.0jp, 8.2 or 8.0)
> - Language support:         (Japanese/English or English Only)
> - Grammar compiler:         (bison or yacc)
> - Lexical analyizer:        (flex or lex)
> - Test for required libs:       (-X11)
> - Test for system-dependent libs:   (-xpg4, -ldl, -lsocket, -lnsl, -lm)
> - Test for long long:       ("1" or "0")
> - Test for optreset requirement:    ("1" or "0")
> - Check OS name to determine signal() semantics: (handler disabled/reenabled on catch)
>
> The following actions are performed:
>
> - config.h is edited to reflect the results of the tests above.
> - Top-level makefile is built using xmkmf
> - Subdirectory (src/common, src/tkgate, src/gsim, src/gmac) makefiles are built using xmkmf
> - Include file links are built
> - Dependencies are built.
>
> Normally the configuration will take place fully automatically, but if
>   some components such as tcl/tk are in non-standard locations you may need to edit config.h and add the required directories to TKGATE_INCDIRS and TKGATE_LIBDIRS.
>
> 3. Edit the file config.h to change the install directory locations if necessary.  By default, executables will be installed in "/usr/X11R6/bin", man pages in "/usr/X11R6/man/man1", and library files in "/usr/X11R6/lib/tkgate-1.6g". Do not edit any of the lines between the BEGIN-AUTO and END-AUTO lines as these will be automatically generated by the configure script.
>
> 4. Edit the file "sitename.txt" to specify the name for the site. This name will appear on traces and circuit diagrams printed by TkGate.  The default name is "Earth" (probably correct for most users, but maybe a little unspecific). Users can also override the site name by editing their preferences.
>
> 5. Compile TkGate using the command:
>
> `make`
>
> 6. Install TkGate using the commands:
>
> ```
>  make install    
>  make install.man
> ```
>
> If you don't have write access to the install directories, you can also run TkGate from the compilation directory which is used as a secondary home directory. You can also explicitly set the home directory by setting the enviornment variable TKGATE_HOME. The executable for tkgate will be in src/tkgate/tkgate.
>
> 7. (optional) Set the protection on the file "tkgate-error.log" in the tkgate home directory to be publicly writable.  TkGate makes internal consistency checks and logs any problems to this file (these are potential problems with TkGate, not with the circuit being edited). If the file is unwritable, errors will be logged to the file of the same name in the current directory. Normally this file should have few or no entries.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Anwar I read the linked  threat and I think I see the point and I agree with it, thanks for showing me. So I understand it would be better if I would explain the  *Readme* installation step by step and Iwould like to edit my asnwer according to that, but OP didnt really say where did he get stuck or what wasn't working so I dont know what to try to explain to him about it.

Comment: You can try including the basics of installation process. But that would be different than apt-getting

Comment: @Anwar I pasted the installation instructions from the README file  into the answer. Even though installation instructions can become obsolete, at least the instructions will give the OP a reference in case he wants to comment about something.